# Retrieving InfoWindowContent with GoogleMapsAPI 3.0 and FusionTablesAPI 1.0

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables, infowindow

I recently received an email from Google advising me to update my map's code. I followed instructions available on their [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/migration_guide). Everything is functioning properly now except the infoWindow. When I type in an address, and hit search, it properly drops the pin on the map but does not open an infoWindow with corresponding content. This is the code snippet that I believe is not correct.

```
var script = document.createElement("script");

    script.setAttribute("src","https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT * FROM " +
        tableid + " WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, CIRCLE(LATLNG(" + coordinate.lat() + "," + coordinate.lng() + "), 0.1))&jsonCallback=addInfoWindow");
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

I've tried both jsonCallback and callback parameters. Both yield the same results.

Thank you for your assistance.

addInfoWindow() ***

```
function addInfoWindow(response) {

 infowindow.close();

if(response.table.rows.length) {
    infowindow.close();
     initialize();
    infowindow.setContent("Content removed: " + response.table.rows[0][1] + response.table.rows[0][0]);
    infowindow.setPosition(coordinate);
    map.setCenter(coordinate);
    map.setZoom(15);
    infowindow.open(map);
}
else
{
infowindow.close();
initialize();

    infowindow.setContent("Nothing here.");
    infowindow.setPosition(coordinate);
    map.setCenter(coordinate);
    map.setZoom(15);
    infowindow.open(map);
}
```

}

**UPDATE: generateInfoWindow()**

```
function generateInfoWindow(results, status) {

    initialize();

if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    initialize();
    //center and zoom map
    coordinate = results[0].geometry.location;

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        layer: layer,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: coordinate
    });
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    map.setZoom(15);






    var script = document.createElement("script");

   script.setAttribute("src","https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT * FROM " +
    tableid + " WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, CIRCLE(LATLNG(" + coordinate.lat() + "," + coordinate.lng() + ")))&key=" + apiKey +  " &callback=addInfoWindow()");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

} else {
    alert("Please make sure you entered your City and State");
}
```

}

Comment: Change jsonCallback to callback. Also, please post the code of your callback function `addInfoWindow()`

Comment: Thanks, @Marcelo. I've updated accordingly.

Comment: Still working on this, @Marcelo. I've tweaked the SQL call a few times with no luck. The entire function is now posted in my question. I would be grateful for another review by you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like: "...)&key=" + apiKey + "&callback=addInfoWindow()"

Comment: Thanks, @Eric. I've updated the script - but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code that focuses on retrieving the data from a Fusion Table. 
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5KVZ6J1ohN_dktpWXBmSzNkdjg/edit

I'm going to guess you don't want this part:  ), 0.1))
... and that you do need the API key.

Hope that helps,

-Rebecca

Comment: Thanks, @Rebecca. I've updated accordingly with no luck. I've added the entire generateInfoWindow(). I did remove .1 from ST_INTERSECTS. Thank you for your help!